# jQuery function which fires dialog not being found

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below fiddle attempts fire a dialog with truncated text when href selected :

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' id="truncatedText" onclick='fnOpenNormalDialog("this is the text to truncate");return false'></a>

$(function(){
$("#truncatedText").text(truncateText('truncate this text'));
})

function truncateText(text) {

var shortText = jQuery.trim(text).substring(0, 20) .split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";

    console.log(shortText)
return shortText

    }

function fnOpenNormalDialog(text) {
    $("#dialog-confirm").html("Confirm Dialog Box");

    // Define the Dialog and its properties.
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Modal",
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(true);
            },
                "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                callback(false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vvjj8/6236/

But the function `fnOpenNormalDialog` is not being found, Chrome error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fnOpenNormalDialog is not defined(index):72 onclick
```

Is the function not defined correctly ?

Comment: if you're using jQuery why are you using the antiquated `onclick` method?  (and it's not defined because the definition of the method isn't declared before you use it).  Changing your demo to simply use the script in the head fixes the problem, please don't do this, write some good jQuery code using [Document Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) and [jQuery on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) event handling.

Comment: where is dialog-confirm in the fiddle?

Comment: @Sushil it doesn't work because of exactly what he stated already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your jsfiddle and have added the missing div.

your link now looks like this

```
<a href='#' id="truncatedText"></a>
<div id='dialog-confirm'></div>
```

try this http://jsfiddle.net/vvjj8/6242/.